# Right answer not accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

How to manage right answer that are not accepted by the user who wrote the question?

It often happened that a user forget to accept a right answer or do not login stackexchange and the reply is not accepted.

What about accept the answer by other users? Maybe needed multiple vote on the answer?

Comment: Are you talking about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? If this is the case, then you probably wanted to write "the user who wrote the *question*" rather than "the user who wrote the *answer*" And maybe also ([meta-tag:accepted-answer]) tag would be worth adding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty much a duplicate of multiple questions on meta.SE (which is the correct place for this kind of question - there's nothing the sports.SE community can do about this); see for example [Would it be possible to have a "community accepted" feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature) or [Force Accepted Answers on Questions by Inactive Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users). If you feel strongly about this, pop over there.